# Writing a Smallf*ck interpreter

Tags: python, algorithm, interpreter

the problem I'm trying to solve is this Codewars kata: https://www.codewars.com/kata/58678d29dbca9a68d80000d7/train/python

I'm passing 123 out of 124 tests, but the one I'm failing is related to how I'm handling nested loops. I just can't seem to figure out a way to replicate the problem because they don't show you the test input. Any help is appreciated; here's what I have for the problem so far:

```
import re

def interpreter(code, tape):
    #Filter out non-command characters
    code_pure = re.findall(r"(\>|\<|\*|\[|\])", code)
    sf = "".join(code_pure)
    #Convert tape to list so that elements are mutable
    tape_list = []
    for bit in tape:
        tape_list.append(bit)
    #Keep track of pointer and instruction position
    pointer = 0
    instr = 0
    brack_pos = [] #Contains positions of "[" brackets
    while instr < len(sf):
        #If pointer goes out of bounds then end the program
        if pointer >= len(tape_list) or pointer < 0:
            return "".join(tape_list)
        #"*" flips the current bit
        if sf[instr] == "*":
            if tape_list[pointer] == "1":
                tape_list[pointer] = "0"
            elif tape_list[pointer] == "0":
                tape_list[pointer] = "1"
            instr += 1
        #Move right one bit
        elif sf[instr] == ">":
            pointer += 1
            instr += 1
        #Move left one bit
        elif sf[instr] == "<":
            pointer -= 1
            instr += 1
        elif sf[instr] == "[":
            #If pointer is on 0, skip the loop
            if tape_list[pointer] == "0":
                brack_cnt = 1
                while brack_cnt != 0:
                    instr += 1
                    if sf[instr] == "[":
                        brack_cnt += 1
                    elif sf[instr] == "]":
                        brack_cnt -= 1
                instr += 1
             #If pointer is 1, step into the loop
            elif tape_list[pointer] != "0":
                brack_pos.append(instr)
                instr += 1
        elif sf[instr] == "]":
            if tape_list[pointer] == "0":
                instr += 1
            elif tape_list[pointer] != "0":
                instr = brack_pos[-1] 
                brack_pos.pop()
    
    return "".join(tape_list)
```

Comment: Please put part of the assignment (or relevant content) also in the question. The link might not be in future working, but SO and your question will be there forever. :)

Comment: I think I see the problem. In that last if-block where you're checking for `sf[instr] == "]"` you never remove the corresponding "["-position when moving past the "]". So in a nested loop the outer loop will jump back to that inner "[" instead. I.e. the `brack_pos.pop()` needs to happen in both cases.

Comment: @Cereal Thank you so much! This did end up being the issue, now i'm passing all the test cases. If you want to post your comment as an actual solution I'll gladly mark it correct. Thanks again!

Comment: @Elision Sure, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the last if-block checking for `sf[instr] == "]"` where `brack_pos.pop()` is executed only when looping back to the opening bracket, not when moving past the closing bracket. I.e. `brack_pos.pop()` needs to be unconditional.

Seems like a fun exercise btw., here's what I came up with:

```
def interpreter(code, tape):
    # Implement your interpreter here
    tape = list(tape)
    # Find matching brackets
    jump = [0]*len(code)
    open_bracket_stack = []
    for i,c in enumerate(code):
        if c == '[':
            open_bracket_stack.append(i)
        elif c == ']':
            matching = open_bracket_stack.pop()
            jump[i] = matching
            jump[matching] = i
    code_ptr = 0
    tape_ptr = 0
    while(code_ptr < len(code) and tape_ptr < len(tape) and tape_ptr >= 0):
        c = code[code_ptr]
        if c == '>':
            tape_ptr += 1
        elif c == '<':
            tape_ptr -= 1
        elif c == '*':
            tape[tape_ptr] = '1' if tape[tape_ptr] == '0' else '0'
        elif c == '[' and tape[tape_ptr] == '0':
            code_ptr = jump[code_ptr]
        elif c == ']' and tape[tape_ptr] == '1':
            code_ptr = jump[code_ptr]
        code_ptr += 1
    return "".join(tape)
```